# Restrict document set

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-set, sharepoint-administration

when I create a document set, I only want certain document types to be created (see screenshot).

[image: Add a document to document set]

How can I restrict the fact that only Word files can be created in the document set?

Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the mistake....it was permission problem. I must have activate "Use Client Integration Features"[image: Permission]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, when I don't add document set content type into the document library, there are four file types to choose.

[image]

When I add document set content type into the document library, there are two file types to choose. You could disable folder in the advanced settings.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where you can find the "advanced settings", where I can set the file types?